# jquery clone div and append it after specific div

Tags: jquery, clone

[image]

From the picture above, I want to clone the div with id #car2 and append it after the last div with id start with car, in this example id #car5. How can I do that?
Thanks.

This is my try code:

```
$("div[id^='car']:last").after('put the clone div here');
```

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You can use clone, and then since each div has a class of car_well you can use insertAfter to insert after the last div.

```
$("#car2").clone().insertAfter("div.car_well:last");
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the same to add multiple attachments to a form.
Can you please explain how to remove this div with a neutral function (so basically, I would have 1 function to add div and another to remove last div)

Comment: This works fine, but html() with an anonymous function is potentially more powerful, depending on application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707756/jquery-clone-div-and-append-it-after-specific-div#answer-47063071

Answer (score 14):

try this out

```
$("div[id^='car']:last").after($('#car2').clone());
```

Comment: And how do I increase the id number to car 6 after clone?

Comment: @Mikeys4u i wasn't sure of the top of my head , I found this thread on the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126395/how-to-jquery-clone-and-change-id

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function of jQuery, Accepted answer is ok but i am providing alternative to it, you can use [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/), but it works only if you can change html slightly as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clone_btn').click(function(){
      $("#car_parent").append($("#car2").clone());
    });
});
```

```css
.car-well{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:3px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="car_parent">
  <div id="car1" class="car-well">Normal div</div>
  <div id="car2" class="car-well" style="background-color:lightpink;color:blue">Clone div</div>
  <div id="car3" class="car-well">Normal div</div>
  <div id="car4" class="car-well">Normal div</div>
  <div id="car5" class="car-well">Normal div</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="clone_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Clone</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works great if a straight copy is in order. If the situation calls for creating new objects from templates, I usually wrap the template div in a hidden storage div and use jquery's html() in conjunction with clone() applying the following technique:

```
<style>
#element-storage {
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
</style>

<script>
$("#new-div").append($("#template").clone().html(function(index, oldHTML){ 
    // .. code to modify template, e.g. below:
    var newHTML = "";
    newHTML = oldHTML.replace("[firstname]", "Tom");
    newHTML = newHTML.replace("[lastname]", "Smith");
    // newHTML = newHTML.replace(/[Example Replace String]/g, "Replacement"); // regex for global replace
    return newHTML;
}));
</script>

<div id="element-storage">
  <div id="template">
    <p>Hello [firstname] [lastname]</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="new-div">

</div>
```