# javascript create div and append it next to a child element without id

Tags: javascript, append, parent-child

Using the solution suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32135318/10279127 i'm trying to create a new div, and append it inside a parent div with id, next to a child `<a>` html element.

html:

```
<div id="div0">
<a href="#" class="link">anchor text</a>
// I'd like to place the new div here
</div>
```

js:

```
Element.prototype.appendAfter = function(element) {
  element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);
}, false;

var NewElement = document.createElement('div');
NewElement.id = 'newDivID';
var tToAfter = $('#div' + index + ' > a'); // this is what i tried but doesn't work
NewElement.appendAfter(tToAfter);
```

If inside `.appendAfter(...)` instead of `tToAfter` i write `document.getElementById('randomElementId')` it works and appends it, so i think must be pure javascript, is there a way in js to do something like: document.getElementById('div' + index).firstChild to get the `<a>` ?

Or to make it entirely with jQuery using the insertAfter (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8707793/10279127) ?

Comment: There's some questions to you: will `<a>` always be the first `div` child? will be other elements inside the `div` between the a tag and the appended tag?

Comment: I feel what you mean, in fact getting the first child wouldn't be best, cause right now it's always the first child but if that changes in the future the code breaks.

Comment: so the rule is: always append after the first `<a>`tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select  inside div#div0 by using

```
const anchor = document.querySelector("#div0>a");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your approach by using [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement). For example (the css is irrelevant - just there so you can visually see the inserted `div`):

```js
const anchor = document.querySelector('#div0 a');
const elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.id = 'newDivID';
anchor.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', elem);
```

```css
div:not(#div0) {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div0">
  <a href="#" class="link">anchor text</a>
  // I'd like to place the new div here
</div>
```