# jQuery 'Add row' function counter issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple form on my website.

The bug: I click the '**Yes**' radio button then click '**Add 1 more**' 3 times and instead of having 4 rows in total, I have about 9 (?).

Give it a try in [the JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/a85cvfhd/). I've also attached here in the post.

I'm assuming it's my Counter but been racking my head with no joy.

```js
$(function() {
    // Initially hide both divs
    $(".bulk").hide();
    $(".individual").hide();
    // Listen for changes in the radio button selection
    $("input[name='bulkPayments']").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
            // Show the bulk div and hide the individual div
            $(".bulk").show();
            $(".individual").hide();
        } else if ($(this).val() === "No") {
            // Show the individual div and hide the bulk div
            $(".bulk").hide();
            $(".individual").show();
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialize the counter for generating unique names and IDs
    var counter = 1;
    // Add more sets when the "Add 1 more" button is clicked
    $("#addMore").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
        // Clone the "bulk" section and update the attributes
        var newBulkSection = $(".bulk:first").clone();
        // Increment the counter for the next set and update the IDs and names
        counter++;
        newBulkSection.find("input[type=text]").attr("id", "clientName" + counter).attr("name", "clientName" + counter);
        newBulkSection.find("input[type=file]").attr("id", "attachments" + counter).attr("name", "attachments" + counter);
        // Clear input values in the new section (optional)
        newBulkSection.find("input[type=text]").val("");
        newBulkSection.find("input[type=file]").val("");
        // Append the newly modified section to the container
        $("#bulkContainer").append(newBulkSection);
        // Show the newly added section
        newBulkSection.show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Bulk Payments *:</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input name="bulkPayments" type="radio" value="Yes"> Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input name="bulkPayments" type="radio" value="No"> No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bulk" id="bulkContainer" style="display:none">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="clientName1">Client Name *:</label> <input autocomplete="one-time-code" class="form-control" id="clientName1" name="clientName1" placeholder="" required="" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="attachments1">Attachment:</label> <input class="form-control-file" id="attachments1" name="attachments1" type="file">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><button class="btn" id="addMore">Add 1 more</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: kindly check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126395/how-to-clone-and-change-id 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707756/jquery-clone-div-and-append-it-after-specific-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `#bulkContainer` and `.bulk` are the same element, so when you clone `.bulk:first` you're cloning *the entire container* with all previous clones within it.

To fix the issue, remove the `.bulk` class from `#bulkContainer` and add it to a new child div, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  // Initially hide both divs
  $("#bulkContainer").hide();
  $(".individual").hide();

  // Listen for changes in the radio button selection
  $("input[name='bulkPayments']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
      // Show the bulk div and hide the individual div
      $("#bulkContainer").show();
      $(".individual").hide();
    } else if ($(this).val() === "No") {
      // Show the individual div and hide the bulk div
      $("#bulkContainer").hide();
      $(".individual").show();
    }
  });

  // Initialize the counter for generating unique names and IDs
  var counter = 1;

  // Add more sets when the "Add 1 more" button is clicked
  $("#addMore").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
    // Clone the "bulk" section and update the attributes
    var newBulkSection = $(".bulk:first").clone();
    // Increment the counter for the next set and update the IDs and names
    counter++;
    newBulkSection.find("input[type=text]").attr("id", "clientName" + counter).attr("name", "clientName" + counter);
    newBulkSection.find("input[type=file]").attr("id", "attachments" + counter).attr("name", "attachments" + counter);
    // Clear input values in the new section (optional)
    newBulkSection.find("input[type=text]").val("");
    newBulkSection.find("input[type=file]").val("");
    // Append the newly modified section to the container
    $("#bulkContainer").append(newBulkSection);
    // Show the newly added section
    newBulkSection.show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Bulk Payments *:</label>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input name="bulkPayments" type="radio" value="Yes"> Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input name="bulkPayments" type="radio" value="No"> No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bulkContainer" style="display:none">
    <div class="bulk">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientName1">Client Name *:</label> <input autocomplete="one-time-code" class="form-control" id="clientName1" name="clientName1" placeholder="" required="" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="attachments1">Attachment:</label> <input class="form-control-file" id="attachments1" name="attachments1" type="file">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" id="addMore">Add 1 more</button>
</form>
```

Also, as an aside, note that creating incremental `id` attributes using a counter variable is not ideal practice. I would strongly suggest you remove that logic and use common classes instead. If you need to identify a specific group of the cloned HTML, use its index.

Here's a demonstration of how to do that:

```js
$(function() {
  const $bulkContainer = $("#bulkContainer");
  const $individual = $('.individual');

  $("input[name='bulkPayments']").on('change', e => {
    const value = $(e.target).val();
    $bulkContainer.toggle(value === "Yes");
    $individual.toggle(value !== "Yes");
  });

  $("#addMore").on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $newBulkSection = $(".bulk:first").clone().insertAfter('.bulk:last');
    $newBulkSection.find("input[type=text], input[type=file]").val("");
  });
});
```

```css
#bulkContainer,
.individual {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Bulk Payments *:</label>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input name="bulkPayments" type="radio" value="Yes"> Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input name="bulkPayments" type="radio" value="No"> No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bulkContainer">
    <div class="bulk">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientName1">Client Name *:</label>
            <input autocomplete="one-time-code" class="form-control" name="clientName" placeholder="" required="" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="attachments1">Attachment:</label>
            <input class="form-control-file" name="attachments" type="file" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" id="addMore">Add 1 more</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ah wow, you're the best Rory - thank you so much. And apologies for such a basic error on my part. Appreciate your time here.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I also just updated the answer with a simplified approach which removes the need for the `counter` variable, or updating the `name`/`id` of the cloned content.

Comment: Ah, and thank you too for that very useful nugget. I'll be sure to keep this in mind and amend my code accordingly. Many thanks Rory.